# Adding geometry from first row of attribute table to all other rows of attribute table of layer using PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a layer where only the first row in the attribute table has a geometry. I want to copy this geometry to all other rows of the attribute table of this layer but the geometry is still empty.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Get the first feature from the layer
feature = layer.getFeatures()
n = next(feature)

# save geometry in variable
geom = n.geometry()
    
# add geometry to all rows of attribute table
layer.startEditing()
for f in layer.getFeatures():
  f.setGeometry(geom)
layer.commitChanges()

# print geometry of all rows of attribute table
for g in layer.getFeatures():
    print (g.geometry())
```

Comment: output of print geometry is: <QgsGeometry: MultiLineString ((390348.37778519437415525 5814565.59899287391453981, 390355.81410851434338838 5815164.22302012797445059))>
<QgsGeometry: null>
<QgsGeometry: null>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Backup first, it will modify the layer in place.

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("thelayer")[0]
pr = layer.dataProvider()

#Fetch the geometry of the first feature
featureiterator = layer.getFeatures()
first_feature = next(featureiterator)
first_geometry = first_feature.geometry()

geometryMap = {} #A dict to store each features id and new geometry

for f in featureiterator: #The first feature is already fetched, so this will continue iterating at the second feature
    geometryMap[f.id()] = first_geometry #For each feature, store its id and the first features geometry in geometryMap dict.

pr.changeGeometryValues(geometryMap) #Apply the geometry map
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!!